# '[pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Invalid date, time or timestamp value' When trying to compare dates

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

I cant get past this error.

I have a date field stored in mmddyy format.

I want to only return records with a date after 12/31/2019.

I get that Pervasive uses yyyy-mm-dd by default.

I am reformatting the date with this code:

```
Convert(Concat('20',Concat(Right(Date,2),Concat('-',Concat(Left(Date,2),Concat('-',Substring(Date)))))),SQL_DATE)
```

A date value of 081820 returns 44061.

```
Convert('2019-12-31',SQL_DATE)
```

returns 43830.

```
And Convert(Concat('20',Concat(Right(Order_Header.Date_Shipped,2),Concat('-',Concat(Left(Order_Header.Date_Shipped,2),Concat('-',Substring(Order_Header.Date_Shipped,3,2)))))),SQL_DATE) > Convert('2019-12-31',SQL_DATE)
```

returns

```
[pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Invalid date, time or timestamp value
```

Ive tried cast and convert... anyone know what I am doing wrong in my And statement (in my where clause) or how I can get around this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have values that are not valid for a date in your data.  You should probably check the records.  The Date specification requires a month of 1 to 12, a day of 1 to 31 depending on the month (so Feb 30 would be invalid), and a year of 0000 to 9999. Something like this for months, you'd want to check days as well:

```
insert into sodate (f1) values ('442020');
insert into sodate (f1) values ('  2020');
select f1, left(f1,2) from sodate where left(f1,2) not in ('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12')
```

The `substring` in the first example is missing parameters.  Once you've got the date in the right format ('yyyy-mm-dd') you should be able to compare it to a date value without converting it to the SQL_DATE data type. One more thing, you're prepending '20' before all years, what happens if your data has dates from pre-2000?  You'll need to account for that.  In the PCC, when I run:

```
select Convert('2019-12-31',SQL_DATE)
```

I get:

```
    EXPR_1
==========
12/31/2019
```

I used the folowing:

```
create table sodate (f1 char(6));
insert into sodate (f1) values ('123119');
insert into sodate (f1) values ('081818');
insert into sodate (f1) values ('081820');
insert into sodate (f1) values ('082020');
select * from sodate;

-- This should give the results you want
select concat(concat(concat(concat(concat('20',right(f1, 2)),'-'),left(f1,2)),'-'),substring(f1,3,2)) from sodate where
concat(concat(concat(concat(concat('20',right(f1, 2)),'-'),left(f1,2)),'-'),substring(f1,3,2)) > '2019-12-31';
-- This query shows you don't need the CONVERT to compare a date.  
select concat(concat(concat(concat(concat('20',right(f1, 2)),'-'),left(f1,2)),'-'),substring(f1,3,2)) from sodate where
```

concat(concat(concat(concat(concat('20',right(f1, 2)),'-'),left(f1,2)),'-'),substring(f1,3,2)) >= now()

And got the following results:

```
EXPR_1        
==============
2019-12-31    
2020-08-18
```

and the second query gives:

```
EXPR_1        
==============
2020-08-20
```

Comment: You sir are a legend. A god among men. I have been learning the ins and outs of PSQL for the past couple months 99% from your comments on other websites. I post here, and you show up almost immediately with the material to help me crack it. My date reformatting logic was giving back 8 rows with '2000-00-00'. Throw in a Case statement, purring like a kitten.